# Is having an endpoint at http: a security risk for the Web Service

Tags: web-services, security, jax-ws, ibm-rad

I have generated a `JAX-WS` `web service` with `RAD 8.5` which automatically generated an endpoint for the service at "http:endpoint".  I generated a client for the `web service` from the `WSDL` and added transport security (SSL) to the `web service` and added a secure endpoint using the following line of code in my client:

```
proxy._getDescriptor().setEndpoint("https:endpoint");
```

Everything seems to work fine.  My question is do I need to do anything about the existence of the original endpoint ant "http:endpoint".  This is an in-house `web service` so all of the apps which use it in house will use the secure endpoint, but is the availability of the unsecure endpoint a security risk for the web service?  If so, what do I need to do to fix it?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Framework you are using, but there should be a configuration in your proxy to not allow http calls at all. If you have that option, turn it on so that your service only listens on port 443 (secure port).

An alternative would be to rewrite all http requests with https.

Comment: I can't find the option to not allow http calls but I appreciate the suggestion.  If I can find the option it would be exactly what I was looking for.